# Routing Error When Updating to Angular version 15

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'text' does not exist in type 'Route'.

[image: Object literal routing error]

src/app/app-routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
      { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, text: "Dashboard" },
      { path: "heroes", component: HeroesComponent, text: "Heroes" },
    ];
```

[image: error showing inline with VSCode Intellisense]

This happened when I ran the update command to get onto Angular v15: `ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15`.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it after seeing this in the breaking changes:
https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#the-title-property-is-required-on-activatedroutesnapshot

Changing `text` to `title` seemed to get rid of the error.

src/app/app-routing.module.ts [old]

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
      { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, text: "Dashboard" },
      { path: "heroes", component: HeroesComponent, text: "Heroes" },
    ];
```

src/app/app-routing.module.ts [new]

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
      { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, title: "Dashboard" },
      { path: "heroes", component: HeroesComponent, title: "Heroes" },
    ];
```